# Scapy + Custom Packet + Code in Payload

Tags: python, scapy

I am trying to create a custom packet using scapy. I have been successful in writing the python script to create the custom packet. But in the payload, instead of inserting raw data, I want to insert a python script which I want to execute on the packet at a later point in time.Is it doable?
Please help me know.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: a=IP(dst="x.x.x.x")/TCP()/Raw(load=data)
But data is some text. I want it to be a python script.

Comment: You should take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.